# Ciclo while, al terminar un área que vuelva a preguntar si desea sacar otra

Tags: java

Lo que me interesa es agregar el ciclo while y que al terminar de sacar un área pregunté si desea sacar otra área y se decide que si volver a mostrar las opciones.

```
package Codigo1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Figuras {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        int 
     LO=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cual area desea calcular?\n1)Circulo\n2)Triangulo\n3)Cuadrado"));

                switch (LO) {
                case 1:
                    int C=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el radio del circulo"));
                    double R=3.1416*(C*C);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del circulo es "+R);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    double h = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la altura del triangulo"));
                    double b=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la base del triangulo"));
                    R=(b*h)/2;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del circulo es "+R);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    int L=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el lado del cuadrado"));
                    R=(L*L);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del cuadrado es "+R);
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual seria el problema que tuviste agregando el ciclo while (porque justamente es lo que pusiste en tu pregunta pero no esta en tu codigo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer primero sobre el codigo es perarlo por metodos ya que al separarlo es mucho mas facil el poder encontrar la solucion a lo que requieres, he cambiado tu clase un poco pero funciona tal cual como dices que necesitas.

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Area;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Figuras {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     Figuras figuras = new Figuras();
     figuras.ejecutable();

    }

   public void ejecutable(){

       Boolean flag = true;

       while(flag){

           this.menu();
           int LO=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Desea volver a consultar?\n1)SI\n2)NO"));

           if(LO == 2){
               flag = false;
           }
       }

   }


  public void menu(){
      int LO=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cual area desea calcular?\n1)Circulo\n2)Triangulo\n3)Cuadrado"));

                switch (LO) {
                case 1:
                    int C=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el radio del circulo"));
                    double R=3.1416*(C*C);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del circulo es "+R);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    double h = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la altura del triangulo"));
                    double b=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la base del triangulo"));
                    R=(b*h)/2;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del circulo es "+R);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    int L=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el lado del cuadrado"));
                    R=(L*L);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del cuadrado es "+R);
                    break;
        }
  }
}
```

Debes tener en cuenta que al separar los metodos del main se puede obtener mucho mas rapido lo que se requiere, por otro lado el bucle while se ejecuta siempre que una condicion se cumpla por eso se declaro una variable boolean que permita que se repita siempre y cuando el valor sea verdadero.

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó, enserio gracias

Comment: Vale, toca que aprendar a separar las funciones por metodos de esa forma se soluciona mas rapido cualquier problema, no olvide calificar la respuesta